# Is there anyway to find(GET) all properties like value,domain,path of a browser cookie using JS/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have browser vulnerability issue to deal with. There are two zipcode cookies in browser, one is set myself, assume the second is set of attacker with same cookie name both different domain name.

My cookie is at domain: .example.com
Attacker cookie is at domain: testing.www.example.com

How could i delete the 2nd cookie? Is there anyway we can determine domain name and path of the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can only get `document.cookie`.

Other `cookie` metadata like the `domain`, `path` etc aren't not visible in JavaScript code (or server-side for that matter.